# Create matrices from a given cell-array of strings with different lengths

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

I have 3 sequences in a cell-array:

```
Input_cell= {'ABCD','ACD', 'ABD'}

 S1= 'ABCD' % which means A<B<C<D
 S2= 'ACD'  % which means A<C<D  % missing B in the full string of 'ABCD'
 S3= 'ABD'  % which means A<B<D  % missing C in the full string of 'ABCD'
```

I want to convert each of the strings in the `Input_cell` into a matrix `M` (`i`-by-`j`) which has to satisfy these conditions:

- `M(i,j)` and `M(j,i)` are random
- `M(i,i) = 0.5`
- `M(i,j) + M(j,i) = 1`
- `M(i,j) < M(j,i)` For example if `A<B` then `M(A,B) < M(B,A)`

For example if we have `S1 = 'ABCD'`  (which means `A<B<C<D`), the `M1` matrix will  be expected as follows:

```
     A      B     C     D
 A  0.5    0.3   0.2   0.1 
 B  0.7    0.5    0    0.4
 C  0.8     1    0.5   0.1
 D  0.9    0.6   0.9   0.5
```

If we have `S2 = 'ACD'` (which means `A<C<D`), missing `B` in the full string of `'ABCD'`, we will put the value `0.5` in every position of `B` in the matrix, the `M2` matrix will be expected as follows:

```
     A      B     C     D
 A  0.5    0.5   0.2   0.1 
 B  0.5    0.5   0.5   0.5
 C  0.8    0.5   0.5   0.1
 D  0.9    0.5   0.9   0.5
```

If we have `S3 = 'ABD'` (which means `A<B<D`), missing `C` in the full string of `'ABCD'`, we will put the value `0.5` in every position of `C` in the matrix, the `M3` matrix will be expected as follows:

```
     A      B     C     D
 A  0.5    0.4   0.5   0.1 
 B  0.6    0.5   0.5   0.3
 C  0.5    0.5   0.5   0.5
 D  0.9    0.7   0.5   0.5
```

How to create that kind of above matrices from a given cell-array of sequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to work out how to do this just for a single sequence:

1. Create a matrix of random numbers between `0.5` and `1`:

   ```
   M = 0.5*rand(4) + 0.5;
   ```
2. Set the main diagonal to equal `0.5`

   ```
   M(logical(eye(4))) = 0.5;
   ```
3. Set the upper triangle of `M` equal to 1 - the lower triangle:

   ```
   M(triu(true(4))) = 1 - M(tril(true(4)));   %// Note the main diagonal doesn't matter...
   ```
4. Work out which letter is missing and set the row and column equal to `0.5` accordingly:

   ```
   fullSeq = 'abcd';
   idx = find(fullSeq == setdiff(fullSeq, 'abd'));
   %// at this point you'll need to check if idx is empty first...
   M(:,idx) = 0.5;
   M(idx,:) = 0.5;
   ```

And now that you can do it for one matrix, just loop over your cell array or else encapsulate this into a function and use `cellfun`.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to use cellfun for this case please ?

Comment: @kgk - you will take all the code as above, make it into a `function` which is trivial and well documented and then just call that function with `cellfun` so if you called it `MyFunc` then you go `cellfun(@MyFunc, Input_cell)` or if you get an error about uniform outputs then `cellfun(@MyFunc, Input_cell, 'Uni', false)`

Comment: Thanks ! But after calling cellfun , I got the error : "Matrix dimensions must agree" .

Comment: Maybe you should ask a new question (linking to this one) specifically about how to make your function work with `cellfun`. Give example data and code again. It's difficult to answer this in the comments. (I'm assuming you got this working using loops already btw)

Comment: please tell me in the case "DCBA" ? Base on the rule above, the matrix should be created in the different way. Right ?

Comment: @kgk can't you just create it as an "ABCD" matrix and then `fliplr`?